# How to get the physical channel configuration of the cellphone via programming

Tags: android, 5g

I want to get the PCI of both primary serving cell and secondary serving cell in 5G NSA, but it seems that I cannot get what I want using getAllCellInfo(). It seems that I need to parse the physical channel configuration as below:

```
{{mConnectionStatus=PrimaryServing,...,mRat=LTE,...,mPhysicalCellId=123},
 {mConnectionStatus=SecondaryServing,...,mRat=NR,...}
```

Does anyone know how to get the (real-time) configuration? Or can I get the PCIs in another way? Thanks very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**About PhysicalChannelConfig**

The only possible way how to obtain `PhysicalChannelConfig` is via [TelephonyManager.registerTelephonyCallback](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager#registerTelephonyCallback(java.util.concurrent.Executor,%20android.telephony.TelephonyCallback)) method. You can for example pass an instance of [TelephonyCallback.PhysicalChannelConfigListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyCallback.PhysicalChannelConfigListener) and you'll start obtaining what you need.

Please note that permission `Manifest.permission.READ_PRECISE_PHONE_STATE` is required, so your app needs to be a system app of carrier-privileged app.

There were some attempts to adjust this protection level, current status can be seen [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/188565322). But as of Android 12 there's no way how to get `PhysicalChannelConfig` if you are a regular developer.

**About PCIs**

You can sometimes get PCIs of serving LTE and NR NSA cells via `getAllCellInfo()` as you mentioned. Sometimes there's one instance of `CellInfoNr` with PCI is present. This behaviour is device-specific.

Generally speaking - Android does not provide any official API you request.